# Spring boot classpath configuration files overrides external application.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to have Spring load an external configuration file if present and else use the once provided in  src/main/resources.

Current setup:

```
src/main/resources/application.properties
src/main/resources/application-dev.properties
src/main/resources/application-prod.properties

/this/is/an/external/dir/application-dev.properties
```

Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/27776123/5126654 I added the following annotations:

```
@EnableFeignClients
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEncryptableProperties
@PropertySources({ //
    @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties"), //
    @PropertySource(value = "file:${external.config}", ignoreResourceNotFound = true) //
})
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

   // ....
}
```

And have the following entry in my application.properties:

```
external.config=/this/is/an/external/dir/application-dev.properties
```

I also can see that the external conifguration file is picked up. The problem I have is that every entry in the classpath properties file overwrites the external ones. I.e. instead of taking entries from
/this/is/an/external/dir/application-dev.properties entries from
src/main/resources/application-dev.properties are taken.

How can I modify my code such that the external file overrides the entries of the classpath file?

Answer (score 0):

Just change the order of importing.
Something like:

```
<context:property-placeholder file-encoding="UTF-8"
                            location="${YOUR_CUSTOM_PATH}/global.properties ,
                                      ${YOUR_CUSTOM_PATH}/local.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
```

or

```
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:global.properties" , "local.properties"},ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
```

In this case the `local.properties` overrides properties of `global.properties`

Comment: Not really working for me..

I think the problem is (for me) is the ordering of the resolution:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config

I have the same properties in the external file and src/main/resource file. For development I want the /src/main/resources file. But for a build application I want to have the application-dev.properties in an external location.

Comment: This could be a good resource for differentiating  development and production environments https://spring.io/blog/2020/04/23/spring-tips-configuration

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want the external config for development, you could as well consider setting external property source as a command line argument in the IDE run configuration for your project.

```
--spring.config.location=/this/is/an/external/dir/application-dev.properties
```

The property source specified in the above manner overrides the application.properties present in class path.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to have Spring load an external configuration file if present and else use the once provided in src/main/resources.

That's the default behavior of Spring Boot. So you just need to enable it correctly.

First of all, remove next annotations, they may disrupt/override the default mechanism:

```
@PropertySources({ //
    @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties"), //
    @PropertySource(value = "file:${external.config}", ignoreResourceNotFound = true) //
})
```

Then specify location of your file as a command line argument:

```
java -jar myapp.jar --spring.config.additional-location=/this/is/an/external/dir/
```

More information here:

- [Spring Boot Features - Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config)
- [Common Application properties - Core properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#core-properties)

Then either rename your config to `application.properties` or specify your `dev` profile (suffix in your file name) via another environmental variable:

```
-Dspring-boot.run.profiles=dev
```

Related question: [Setting active profile and config location from command line in spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31038250/setting-active-profile-and-config-location-from-command-line-in-spring-boot)